# Invalid authorizer ID specified. Setting the authorization type to JWT requires a valid JWT authorizer- Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, hashicorp

I am trying to deploy a HTTP API via terraform and I keep getting an issue with my JWT Authorizer. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. I have looked through documentation but still can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

authorizer.tf

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "jwt_authorizer_bulk_import_s3" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main.id
  authorizer_type  = "JWT"
  identity_sources = ["$request.header.Authorization"]
  name             = "jwt-authorizer"

  jwt_configuration {
    audience = ["removed for now"]
    issuer   = "removed for now"
  }
}


resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "bulk_import_s3" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main.id
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"

  connection_type           = "INTERNET"
  description               = "Processing Data lambda."
  integration_method        = "POST"
  integration_uri           = lookup(var.process_to_s3, "invoke_arn")
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "process_to_s3" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main.id
  route_key          = "POST /process_to_s3/{proxy+}"
  authorization_type = "JWT"

  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.bulk_import_s3.id}"
}
```

Comment: Which resource returned the error?

Comment: So I am now getting this error because I made use of a JWT Authorizer. I have updated my question. As soon I set authrization_type to NONE it's fine but when I changed it to JWT I get issues @jordanm

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. The error I'm getting is as follows:

│ Error: updating API Gateway v2 route (d83o006): BadRequestException: Unable to update route. Authorizer type is invalid or null.
│ 
│   with module.root.module.fastapi-dev.aws_apigatewayv2_route.proxy_lambda_routes["/docs"],
│   on modules/fastapi/main.tf line 207, in resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "proxy_lambda_routes":
│  207: resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "proxy_lambda_routes" {

Comment: Which version of the aws provider are you using?